# In ExtJS 4, How do you delete a tree node when the associated grid information to the node is deleted at random

Tags: extjs

My code so far populates via drag and drop tree nodes and leaves from a grid panel. I want to know how to remove a tree node when the grid information associated with it is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like id property in your model both in grid and tree. So when you remove record in the grid you then search for the node with this id in tree and remove it as well. Another way is just save the reference to the node when you drop it.

The flow is:

1. user drags and drops record from grid to the tree
2. when the record is dropped and new node is created you save reference in the grid's record

   onNodeDrop: function(){
     grid.getSelected().treeNode = tree.lastCreatedNode;
   }
3. then when you delete record in grid you could delete node as well.

Note - this is just a psuedocode, is won't work. Just to give you an idea.